# Bootstrap3 Navbar toggle not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in my website to make it responsive (I will be making a custom design and not use bootstrap's default css). I have created a bootstrap3 navbar but the button which appears after shrinking the viewport does not function as nothing happens when it is clicked.
I have searched for this on stackoverflow and even tried incorporating changes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075248/problems-with-the-responsive-navbar-in-bootstrap-3). But its not working.
Javascript is enabled in my browser and I have referenced bootstrap.js in my html as well.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbackcolor" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="comnWdth">    
               <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --> 
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="number">X12 X123 X123</span>
                    <span class="text">10am-7pm Mon-Sat</span>
                </div>    


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>                        
                        <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="baskit">My Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </div>  <!-- End .comnWdth -->
        </div> <!-- End container -->
    </div> <!-- End Navbar -->
```

Also the toggle button and header ("X12 X123 X123 10am-7pm Mon-Sat") is appearing in different rows when collapsed. How can I make them appear in the same row when in a narrow viewport?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 3, you should use navbar-right instead of pull-right inside a navabr:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">.
```

As for your second question, you should probably post it separately, and include your css because there are clearly custom classes there `"text"` and `"number"` that we'll need to know to make good suggestions.

Comment: hey thanks for your help..the issue was that I had not referenced jquery in my html. The navbar collapse does not work without jquery.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Pull-right working for you?

Comment: I changed my entire code as we decided to have a different mobile layout than the default bootstrap collapse. I added about 7 collapsible buttons with further sub-menus.